# How do I show that there exists only one group of order 2 up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove that exists only one group of order $2$ up to isomorphisme.

My first approach would be to suppose that there are two groups, and show that they are identical. Like supposing that $(G, \cdot)$ and $(G', \star)$ are both groups of order two, whose elements are $e,a \in G$ and $e',a' \in G$ ($e$ and $e'$ are the identity elements) and ultimately showing that their multiplicative table gives the same table, and that there exists a isomorphism $f : G\rightarrow G'$ such that $f(a)=a'$ and $f(e)=e'$.

But it seems to me that this approach is far from being rigorous, and so any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Why do you think this approach is far from being rigorous?

Comment: @tommyxu3 Usually just drawing a table isn't enough.

Comment: Oh, I omitted that sentence, and just see the isomorphism. Then you can directly if it is an isomorphism!

Comment: The multiplication table for a group completely determines the group. Explicitly giving the multiplication table for a finite group is a perfectly rigorous way of defining the group. In this question, however, the emphasis is on the isomorphism: you have defined the right function $f$, it is obviously a bijection and so you have to show that it is a group homomorphism (which you can do by reference to the multiplication tables, if you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can directly check that there is an isomorphism from $(G,e)$ to $(G',e'),$ say $G=\{e,a\}$ and $G'=\{e',a'\}.$ Then clearly $a^2=e$ and $a'^2=e'.$ Consider the map $G\to G'$ by mapping $e$ to $e'$ and $a$ to $a'.$ Then it's a bijection by the construction. What you have to check is that it's a homomorphism(almost trivial).

(This may rephrase what you want to convey by your tables!)